# Cordova File Plugin - returning a value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

using the Cordova-File-Plugin how is it possible to return a value form a callback function?

For example with the following code:

```
function createFile() {
var type = window.TEMPORARY;
var size = 5*1024*1024;
window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback)

function successCallback(fs) {
  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
     alert('File creation successfull!')
  }, errorCallback);
}

function errorCallback(error) {
  alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
}

}
```

How can I return a value, so if the file creation is successful return the value 10; and if false/error return the error.code;

So a button press would call a function then it would call the createFile() function and return a value to the original function from which to work.

i.e, 1. button press that calls function.
2. this function calls createFile();
3. createFile() returns a value;

I have been stuck on this for a while.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check this question out, I answered the same thing here: [Returning a value from Cordova file plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65766037/returning-a-value-from-cordova-file-plugin-when-called-from-a-function/65766367#65766367)

But in your case you would have to change the `returnValue` to `error.code` because you want that to return in your function when there is an error.

```
function createFile() {
var returnValue;
var type = window.TEMPORARY;
var size = 5*1024*1024;
window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback)

function successCallback(fs) {
  fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
     alert('File creation successfull!')
     returnValue = "success";
  }, errorCallback);
}

function errorCallback(error) {
  alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
  returnValue = error.code;
}
return returnValue
}
```