# Returning a value from Cordova File Plugin when called from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, plugins, phonegap

I have seen someone has posted a similar question but it doesn't really fit what I'am looking for:

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnTest").bind("click", function(){
    a = createFile();
      alert(">> "+a); // Displayed returned value;
  });

  function createFile(){
    var type = window.TEMPORARY;
    var size = 5*1024*1024;
    window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback)

    function successCallback(fs) {
      fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        alert('File creation successfull!');
        return 1; // Return value;
      }, errorCallback);
    }

    function errorCallback(error) {
      alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
      return 2; // Return value;
    }
    }   
});
```

Basically once the createFile() function is called it will return either 1 (success) or 2 (error). Problem is I do not know how I can return the value and call it properly?

Any help would be really good.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a global variable in your function called `returnValue` and set its value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btnTest").bind("click", function(){
    a = createFile();
      alert(">> "+a); // Displayed returned value;
  });

  function createFile(){
    var returnValue;
    var type = window.TEMPORARY;
    var size = 5*1024*1024;
    window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback)

    function successCallback(fs) {
      fs.root.getFile('log.txt', {create: true, exclusive: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        alert('File creation successfull!');
        returnValue = 1; // Return value;
      }, errorCallback);
    }

    function errorCallback(error) {
      alert("ERROR: " + error.code)
      returnValue = 2; // Return value;
    }
    return returnValue;
  }
    
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply but the value that is returned comes back as undefined - rather than the value of the global return value variable.

Comment: whoops it's because I missed a bracket, check again

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but it always returns zero (0).

Comment: Are your success or error callbacks running? Because if they are, then you can try to restructure it so that the callbacks return the value you want and you set that equal to your `returnValue`

Comment: Yes, - the two alerts work correctly (i.e, File Creations Successful or the Error Code is shown) as they should but the returnValue is always zero.

Comment: If you remove the original value does it return undefined? I'm confused as to why it would not work

Comment: If you have just - var returnValue, it returns undefined.  If you change it to var returnValue = 20; or var returnValue = 50 it returns that value.  Sadly it doesn't return the value in either of the success/error callback.